# Transform Dirichlet condition into mixed boundary condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If I have a homgeneous linear differential equation like this one (or any other eq):
$$y''(x)-y'(x)=0$$
And they give me these Dirichlet boundary conditions:
$$y(0)=y(1)=0$$
Can I transform them into a mixed boundary conditions?:
$$y(0)=y'(1)=0$$
I tried solving the equation, derivating it and using the original boundary conditions but I don't get anything.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: I dont know, since it is related to physics and differential equations. I will try there, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is in general not possible to obtain conditions on the derivative of a function just from its value at a point.

Note that setting $u=y'$ you need to solve $u'=u$, then integrate $u$ to obtain $y$. The solution will have two constants which you need to adjust to satisfy the boundary conditions, which in this case force the trivial solution.